# How to filter a property in Django

Tags: python, django

I am currently having trouble with filtering data.

**Model**

```
class Member(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    team_id = models.UUIDField(null=True)
    username = models.CharField('', max_length=30)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @property
    def organization_id(self):
        """This is to get the organization Id
        """
        team = Team.objects.get(pk=self.team_id)
        return team.organization_id
```

and now I am planning to filter all the members with the organation_id = **1**.

This is what I need:

```
memberList = Member.objects.filter(organization_id='1')
```

So I got this error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'organization_id' into field. Choices are: id, is_active, team_id, username
```

How can I filter the members using organization_id?

Comment: You are doing a queryset filter which translates to SQL and is executed against the database. The database does not have a field `organization_id`. Since your databases are not connected through a foreign key, you would have to run this as 2 separate queries.

Comment: If you want to query / filter over multiple tables they have to be connected by foreign keys. A loose coupling with UUIDs is not enough.

Comment: Use **organization_id()** in the place of **organization_id** with a for loop, cf my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any field named organization_id in you model **Member**, that's why the error.

Intead you might want this :

```
result_list = []
memberList = Member.objects.all()

for item in memberList :
    if item.organization_id() == '1' :
        result_list.append(item)

print result_list
```

The resultant list **result_list** will contain all the required objects of model **Member**.

Thanks.

Comment: But I am worried about using Member.objects.all() because it might be slow if there will be millions of members

Comment: @JamesReid Member.objects.all() does not hit the database until you iterate the result. And the same computation cost will be there if you use Member.objects.filter() because that also will check all the records of the database.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understood from your questions, I assumeed that you have Two Model class.

Lets make example

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Member(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
```

You use UUIDField as Primary Key. I omitted it. Django make primary key field automatically. I am curious what was your purpose to use UUID Field in the first place.

Anyway, if you create Organization first time. PK number will be 1.

Lets say you are testing in python shell

```
python manage.py shell
>> import your models
>> Organization.objects.create(name="test1")
```

then you can connect this Organization with Foreign Key relationship.

```
>> organization = Organization.objects.get(name="test1")
>> Member.objects.create(username="bob", team=organization)
```

Next time if you want to get members who in test1 organization.

```
>> organization = Organization.objects.get(name="test1")
>> Member.objects.filter(team=organization)
```

or just put PK number of organization 'test1'. Let's say it's 1

```
>> Member.objects.filter(team=1)
```

If fixed that you only want to get members who have organization '1', you can add custom manager in model.

```
class OrganizationManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(team=1)

class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Member(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Organization)

    objects = models.Manager()
    organization = OrganizationManager()
```

you can get members like below

```
>> Member.organization.all()
```

it will return members who are in organization pk 1.

Comment: additionally, your code is  `username = models.CharField('', max_length=30)` I wonder if you wanted to make blank is available. Check blank attribute in Django Manual

Answer (score 0):

```
memberList = Member.objects.all().annotate(org_id=F('calculate organization id over other model fields')).filter(org_id='1')
```

in my case this helps, there F is

```
from django.db.models import F
```